# copying data from database with the same skeleton

Tags: sql-server, database-design, windows, data

I have a database design with the same tables, procedures and all other details on two different servers. Since one of them ran out of traffic, I forwarded the web software project to the other one.

I want to create insert into codes for all table data between the last 15 days (January 15 - January 31, 2024) from server A and add them manually to server B.

I am aware that codes are generated with the Generate script, but it pulls the whole table, I do not want to select search from it, I want it to directly generate the insert into code between these dates.

The database is SQL server and the server is Windows Server.

Comment: Does your tables have foreign keys? Does every table have a timestamp field of when the row changed last?

Comment: not foreign key column but have datetime column

Comment: Roughly, how many tables are there?

Comment: total table count 6

Comment: Please edit the question to add more information